# How to count row from table2 based on table1 include null?

Tags: mysql

I want to count rows from table2 based on table1 id. Everything works well until table2 have no related id. I want the return to be zero rather skip it.

Here's my code:

```
     Select *, 
      Count(pic.pic_id) As npic
       From photo_db pic
 Inner Join products_db prd 
         On pic.pic_sid=prd.prd_sid
   Group By pic.pic_sid
```

Because the file from photo_db is somehow not yet uploaded so no data there. Is there any possibility?

Comment: try to use `left join` or `right join` not `inner join` one of the two should work. There is `full join` but so much data entry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use left join instead of inner join

```
select pic.pic_sid, count(pic.pic_id) as npic
from photo_db pic
left join products_db prd on pic.pic_sid=prd.prd_sid
group by pic.pic_sid
```

Comment: @Wilf, yes you can